installing ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server on windows 10 and windows 11
can we install ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server on windows 10 and windows 11.
ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server is already there on the machines. So can we have multiple drivers on the same without affecting the existing driver?
